# LinkedIn connection counting

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, addeventlistener

I am currently developing a Chrome extension designed to count connections to an account on LinkedIn. I have successfully implemented the counting functionality when visiting the profile page or when performing a search. However, the counting does not work on the network page where it is not necessary to validate the connection request.

In my code, I have included a condition that checks if the confirmation has been performed before executing the counting.

```
// Fonction pour vérifier la présence de la div avec la classe spécifique
function verifierDivSpecifique() {
  // Sélectionnez la div avec la classe spécifique
  var divSpecifique = document.querySelector(
    ".artdeco-modal.artdeco-modal--layer-default.send-invite"
  );

  // Vérifiez si la div a été trouvée
  if (divSpecifique) {
    // Sélectionnez le bouton "Envoyer" avec aria-label commençant par "Envoyer"
    var boutonEnvoyer = divSpecifique.querySelector(
      'button[aria-label^="Envoye"]'
    );

    // Vérifiez si le bouton "Envoyer" a été trouvé
    if (boutonEnvoyer) {
      // Ajouter un gestionnaire d'événements pour le clic sur le bouton "Envoyer"
      boutonEnvoyer.addEventListener("click", function () {
        // Incrémenter le compteur
        verifierJourSemaine();
      });
      return;
    } else {
      // Sélectionnez le bouton "Send" avec aria-label commençant par "Send"
      var boutonSend = divSpecifique.querySelector(
        'button[aria-label^="Send"]'
      );
      // Vérifiez si le bouton "Send" a été trouvé
      if (boutonSend) {
        // Ajouter un gestionnaire d'événements pour le clic sur le bouton "Send"
        boutonSend.addEventListener("click", function () {
          // Incrémenter le compteur
          verifierJourSemaine();
        });
        return;
      }
    }
  }
```

I added a condition to execute the counting function (verifierJourSemaine()) even without checking the "Send" button. However, this doesn't work and even prevents the counting from proceeding correctly.

```
  // Vérifier si l'URL de la page contient des indications spécifiques à la page du réseau LinkedIn
  else if (window.location.href.includes("linkedin.com/mynetwork/")) {

    // Sélectionnez le bouton "Se Connecter" avec aria-label commençant par "Inviter"
    var boutonConnecter = divSpecifique.querySelector(
      'button[aria-label^="Inviter"]'
    );

    // Vérifier si le bouton "Se connecter" a été trouvé
    if (boutonConnecter) {
      // Ajouter d'un gestionnaire d'événements
      boutonConnecter.addEventListener("click", function () {
        // Incrémenter le compteur
        verifierJourSemaine();
      });
    }
  }
```

Can you help me, please? I hope my explanations are clear.

I tried to add a condition for it to execute, I tried without any condition, but nothing happens.
I attempted to modify the function where it is used, but nothing changes.

```
  if (!boutonSeConnecter) {
    boutonSeConnecter = document.querySelector(
      'button[class^="artdeco-button"][class$="artdeco-button--secondary"]'
    );
    boutonSeConnecter.addEventListener("click", function () {
      verifierJourSemaine();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question about your _code_. Also take the [tour].